# access variable declared in a %%bash cell from another jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In a jupyter notebook I have a bash jupyter cell as follows:

```
%%bash

export MYVAR="something"
```

I would like to access `$MYVAR` in a different python cell. For example

```
print(MYVAR)
```

I would expect the cell to print "something", but I get a NameError message.

Example image:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try capturing the output to a python variable:

In [1]:

```sh
%%bash --out my_var

MYVAR="something"
echo "$MYVAR"
```

In [2]:

```sh
print(my_var)
```

```
something
```

Also, you might find [this](http://mmcdan.github.io/posts/interacting-with-the-shell-via-jupyter-notebook/) blog post useful.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to store the output of variable from bash cell into a temp file, and then read it in python cell or other bash cell. For example

#### Bash cell

```
%%bash
my_var="some variable"

echo $my_var > /tmp/my_var
```

#### Python cell

```
my_var = !cat /tmp/my_var
print(my_var)
```

Output is: ['some variable']